# Getting nullpointer with TextView

Tags: java, android

I am getting a nullPointerException when getting a textview in Android. It seems like somedays  I can set TextViews and it will work and somedays it wont. Can someone explain to me as to why I would be getting a nullpointer from this? It is in the method setTextView() the first line, and it is being called from the Net class.

```
package com.tsunamistudios.computerwatch;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OptionalDataException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Client extends Activity {

    private static String message;
    private static ArrayList<Program> programs = new ArrayList<Program>();
    private static Net net;
    private TextView txtView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);   
        new Thread(net = new Net()).start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.client, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        Client.message = message;
    }

    public ArrayList<Program> getPrograms() {
        return programs;
    }

    public void setTextView() {
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        txtView.setText(getPrograms().get(0).getName() + getPrograms().get(0).getDescription());
    }

    public void setPrograms(ArrayList<Program> programs) {
        Client.programs = programs;
    }

    public Net getNet() {
        return net;
    }

    public void setNet(Net net) {
        Client.net = net;
    }


    public TextView getTxtView() {
        return txtView;
    }
}
```

Net.java

```
package com.tsunamistudios.computerwatch;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.OptionalDataException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Net extends Client implements Runnable {

    private static Socket echoSocket;
    private static PrintWriter out;
    private static BufferedReader in;
    private static ObjectInputStream inFromServer;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String hostName = "192.168.0.105";
            int portNumber = 6984;
            echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
//          out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
//          in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
            inFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(echoSocket.getInputStream());   

            getPrograms().add((Program) getProgramsFromObject());           

            setTextView(getTxtView());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    public static Socket getEchoSocket() {
        return echoSocket;
    }

    public Object getProgramsFromObject() {     
        try {
            if(getObjectInputStream() != null) {
                return getObjectInputStream().readObject();
            } else {
                return new Program("Nullpointer", "NullPointer", "Null", null);
            }
        } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void setEchoSocket(Socket echoSocket) {
        Net.echoSocket = echoSocket;
    }

    public static PrintWriter getOut() {
        return out;
    }

    public static void setOut(PrintWriter out) {
        Net.out = out;
    }

    public static BufferedReader getIn() {
        return in;
    }

    public ObjectInputStream getObjectInputStream() {
        return inFromServer;
    }

    public static void setInFromServer(ObjectInputStream inFromServer) {
        Net.inFromServer = inFromServer;
    }

    public static void setIn(BufferedReader in) {
        Net.in = in;
    }

}
```

xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Client" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="162dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error

```
12-21 12:57:17.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30909): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1266
12-21 12:57:17.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30909): Process: com.tsunamistudios.computerwatch, PID: 30909
12-21 12:57:17.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30909): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 12:57:17.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30909):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1884)
12-21 12:57:17.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30909):    at com.tsunamistudios.computerwatch.Client.setTextView(Client.java:47)
12-21 12:57:17.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30909):    at com.tsunamistudios.computerwatch.Net.run(Net.java:30)
12-21 12:57:17.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30909):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: `txtView` is null. post your xml layout and post the net class

Comment: there is something wrong happening when android use `findViewById` to find your view. please post your xml.

Comment: And why do you have this `new Thread(net = new Net()).start();`

Comment: I updated my post. I have that because to use sockets you cant have a network on your main thread.

Comment: @Minor post Net Class and move the initialization to onCreate. you can't update ui from a thread.

Comment: I posted the net class but if I do that then it will update my ui before Net gets the object.

Comment: @Minor no initialization code can go into oncreate. But you can't update ui from te thread

Comment: by initialization what code are you meaning, the objectStream in run() in Net?

Comment: what @Raghunandan meant is that you move `txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);` in `onCreate()`

Comment: But move it to where?

Comment: @Minor `setTextView(getTxtView());` the activity `setTextView()` does not have param `public void setTextView()`. use a asynctask

Comment: @Minor try putting `txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);` below `setContentView(R.layout.activity_client); `

Comment: I did and I put setTextView(txtView) back in CLient after net.start() but I get a index out of bounds exception because programs hasnt been set yet in the net thread, so it needs to wait for Net.

Comment: @Minor use asynctask. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

Your `Net` class is declared as

```
public class Net extends Client implements Runnable {
```

By inheritance hierarchy, it also extends `Activity` which has a `window` instance variable which will be initialized to `null` by default.  When you call

```
 setTextView(getTxtView());
```

it calls the inherited method

```
public void setTextView() {
    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
    txtView.setText(getPrograms().get(0).getName() + getPrograms().get(0).getDescription());
}
```

But because your `Net` is an `Activity` that hasn't been given a `Window` by Android, it fails internally. The [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.findViewById%28int%29) of `Activity` is

```
public View findViewById(int id) {
    return getWindow().findViewById(id);
}
```

where `getWindow()` will return `null`.

You will have to rethink your design. Is `Net` really meant to be an `Activity`?

Comment: will it not become overloaded coz `setTextView(getTxtView());` takes param and `public void setTextView()` no param in that case

Comment: @Raghunandan I would guess OP is showing us some unsynchronized code, because there is no other `setTextView` method. But you are right.

Comment: I changed some code, removed the extends Client but things don't work correctly if I do setTextView() in onCreate because it goes before Net has finished recieving the object I need.